# Something is wrong with my user validation

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to put together code for a menu, and I must validate the user input in the get_menu() function. My problem is that input is not recognized when I make a menu choice, if I choose option 3 , then try to choose a lower option such as option 1 or 2 the menu function comes back up, and then on the second time the input is accepted. the same thing is happening with option two and if I choose a lower option. But going from 1 --> 2, or 1 -->3, or 2-->3, the input is accpeted on the shot.
 I think it is an indentation problem but I cant see it. thanks for any insight :)

```
#define empty place holder variables
menu_choice = ''
number = ()
Binary_Output = ''
decimal_result = ()

#Constants for the menu choices
CONVERT_TO_BINARY_CHOICE = '1'
CONVERT_TO_DECIMAL_CHOICE = '2'
BINARY_COUNTING_CHOICE = '3'
QUIT_CHOICE = '4'

print('\n')
#Defining the get_menu_choice function, which returns the menu choice value.
def get_menu_choice():
    print ('    *** Menu ***')
    print ('\n')
    print ('1. Convert to binary')
    print ('2. Convert to decimal')
    print ('3. Binary counting')
    print ('4. Quit')
    print ('\n')
    menu_choice = input('What would you like to do? [1, 2, 3, 4,]?')
    while menu_choice != '1' or menu_choice != '2' or menu_choice != '3' or menu_choice != '4':
        input("Invalid input please enter either 1, 2, 3, or 4: ")
        return menu_choice
    else:
        return menu_choice

def convert_to_binary(decimal_number):
    print('\n')
    decimal_number = int(input('Please enter number: '))
    while decimal_number != int(decimal_number) in range(0,9):
        int(input('Please enter a valid number: '))
    #while decimal_number == 
    Binary_Output = ''
    while decimal_number > 0:
        #This will concantenate the remainder into a string
        Binary_Output += str(decimal_number % 2)
        #This will perform floor division on the base 10 number
        decimal_number = (decimal_number // 2)
    #the value of Binary_Output is returned
    return Binary_Output


def convert_to_decimal(binary_number):
    print('\n')
    #The binary input to be converted, entered as a string.
    binary = input('Please enter binary number: ')
    #Assigned an empty value here ready to be reassigned in the for loop
    decimal = int()
    #For each iteration in the loop,  indiviually evaluate each digit in the string named binary
    for digit in binary:
        #Stores the result of decimal x 2 + value of the integer either 1 or 0 to decimal 
        #example (((1 * 2+1)*2+0)*2+0)*2+1
        decimal = decimal * 2 + int(digit)
    #loop is finished and the funtion returns the final value for decimal
    return decimal

def Binary_counting():
    print('\n')
    #Declaring the value of decimal_number through user input as an integer
    decimal_number = int(input('Please enter number: '))
    #A counter to set the bottom value of the the comparison loop
    counter = 1
    #User input is used as the value for the loop's upper limit
    upper_range = int(decimal_number)
    #The main loop using the counter and upper limit values
    while counter <= upper_range:
        #empty local values for the function
        binary = ''
        decimal_number = counter
        #Binary conversion of the decimal numbers until it reaches the upper limit
        while decimal_number > 0:
            binary += str(decimal_number % 2)
            decimal_number = (decimal_number // 2)
        #Reverse the string before displaying it
        binary = binary[::-1]
        #Printing of the counter value and binary value are in this code
        print('Decimal:', counter, end=' ',)
        print(' = binary:' , binary)
        #Counter is iterated here
        counter = counter + 1


#Main while loop to set the menu choice
while menu_choice != QUIT_CHOICE:
    menu_choice = get_menu_choice()


    while menu_choice == CONVERT_TO_BINARY_CHOICE:
        number = convert_to_binary(number)
        print('\n')
        print ('Binary Number : ', end=' ')
        print(number[::-1])
        print('\n')
        menu_choice = get_menu_choice()

    while menu_choice == CONVERT_TO_DECIMAL_CHOICE:
        print('\n')
        decimal_result = convert_to_decimal(decimal_result)
        print(decimal_result)
        print('\n')
        menu_choice = get_menu_choice()

    while menu_choice == BINARY_COUNTING_CHOICE:
        print('\n')
        Binary_counting()
        menu_choice = get_menu_choice()

if menu_choice == QUIT_CHOICE:
    print('Goodbye')
```

Comment: print('\n')
    decimal_number = input('Please enter number: ')
    'while decimal_number.isalpha() or decimal_number == '':
        print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-9 only. ")
        decimal_number = input('Please enter number: ')'

Comment: I'm answering my own question now :) but I did eventually  find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this for the user input validation, it works well and stops alpha input and empty input :)

```
print('\n')
decimal_number = input('Please enter number: ')
while decimal_number.isalpha() or decimal_number == '':
    print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-9 only. ")
    decimal_number = input('Please enter number: ')
```